# Are the SmtpClient.SendMailAsync methods Thread Safe?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, async-await

The [SmtpClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4971yhhc.aspx) states that instance members are not thread safe.  This can be seen if concurrent calls are made to [Send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc.aspx) or [SendAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h.aspx).  Both methods will throw a InvalidOperationException on the second call if the first has not yet completed.

The method [SendMailAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193922.aspx), introduced in .NET 4.5, does not list InvalidOperationException as a thrown exception.  Do the new .NET 4.5 methods implement some sort of queuing?  Reflector isn't able to shed any light on the implementation details of this class, so I assume this has been implemented in native methods.

Can multiple threads call the SendMessageAsync method on a shared instance of the SMTP client safely?

Comment: Methods that are not thread-safe are not required to throw an exception if you access them from multiple threads.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not sure why using Reflector didn't work for you. If I decompile it, I see the following code:

```
[HostProtection(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, ExternalThreading=true)]
public Task SendMailAsync(MailMessage message)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    SendCompletedEventHandler handler = null;
    handler = delegate (object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e) {
        this.HandleCompletion(tcs, e, handler);
    };
    this.SendCompleted += handler;
    try
    {
        this.SendAsync(message, tcs);
    }
    catch
    {
        this.SendCompleted -= handler;
        throw;
    }
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

As you can see, it's a simple TAP wrapper for `SendAsync()`. And if `SendAsync()` throws an exception, `SendMailAsync()` just rethrows it.

So, the conclusion is that **`SendMailAsync()` is not thread-safe** and that its exceptions are underdocumented.

Comment: I guess I'm stuck implementing my own queuing mechanism then.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: @brianfeucht Why don't you use multiple instances of `SmtpClient` instead (one for each thread)?

Comment: That is the plan.  Create a pool of SmtpClients so that I can control how many connections a machine makes.  If a client is available it will be shared.  If the pool is completely used the request will be queued for the next available client.

Comment: The throw statements there will cause the method to fail on the poor caller before he had a chance to call await. Isn't this a bug in MS's code?

Comment: @Menahem I wouldn't call it a bug, but it might be better the way you suggest (the caller gets the exception only after `await`ing the `Task`). You might want to consider opening an issue in [the corefx repo](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx). But it might not be changed anyway, because of backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

As a note (since I don't have enough points to comment), the traditional way to write an asynchronous operation was to use the Asynchronous Programming Model (APM), but today we typically use the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP) with its async/await keywords. And although it's not unusual to see TAP wrappers around APM methods, it's also possible to see APM wrappers around TAP methods.